# Firebase response: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to save data into Firebase storage.
Generally, my method and function works, in FireBase logs I get:

> - Function execution took 1442 ms, finished with status code: 201
> - alert15
> - alert14: null||[object Object]
> - alert12:
> - alert11:
> - Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove
>     these restrictions
> - Function execution started

**My function:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require("cors")({origin: true});
const fs = require("fs");
const UUID = require("uuid-v4");

const gcconfig = {
    projectId: "myrojectid",
    keyFilename: "mykeyfile.json"
};

const gcs = require("@google-cloud/storage")(gcconfig);

// // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
//
exports.storeImage = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    console.log("alert11: ")
    cors(request, response, () => {
        console.log("alert12: ")
        const body = JSON.parse(request.body);
        fs.writeFileSync("/tmp/uploaded-image.jpg", body.image, "base64", err => {
            console.log(err => console.log("alert13: " + err));
            return response.status(500).json({error: err})
        });
        const bucket = gcs.bucket("myapp.appspot.com");
        const uuid = UUID();
        bucket.upload(
            "/tmp/uploaded-image.jpg",
            {
                uploadType: "media",
                destination: "/places2/" + uuid + ".jpg",
                metadata: {
                    metadata: {
                        contentType: "image/jpeg",
                        firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
                    }
                }
            }, (err, file) => {
                console.log("alert14: " + err + "||" + file)
                if (!err) {
                    console.log("alert15");
                    response.status(201).json({
                        imageUrl:
                            "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" +
                            bucket.name +
                            "/o/" +
                            encodeURIComponent(file.name) +
                            "?alt=media&token=" +
                            uuid
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log("alert16: ")
                    console.log(err);
                    response.status(500).json({error: err})
                }
            });
    });
});
```

**My method:**

```
import {ADD_PLACE, DELETE_PLACE} from './actionTypes';

export const addPlace = (placeName, location, image) => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch("https://us-central1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/storeImage", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                image: image.base64
            })
        })
            .catch(err=> console.log(err))
            .then(res => {res.json(); console.log("alert2 " + {res})})
            .then(parsedRes => {
                console.log("alert1: " + parsedRes);
                const placeData = {
                    name: placeName,
                    location: location,
                    image: parsedRes.imageUrl
                };
                return  fetch("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/places.json", {
                    method: "POST",
                    body: JSON.stringify(placeData)
                }).catch(err => console.log("alert13: " + err))
            })
            .catch(err => console.log("alert4", err))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .catch(err => console.log("alert5: " + err))
            .then(parsedRes => {
                console.log("alert6", parsedRes);
            }).catch(err => console.log("alert17: " + err));
    };
};

export const deletePlace = (key) => {
    return {
        type: DELETE_PLACE,
        placeKey: key
    };
};
```

but in local console in my IDE I got this:

> - alert1: undefined
> - 'alert4', { [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'parsedRes.imageUrl')]

I wasted 3 days for this and still 0 progress.
What can be wrong here ? How to fix it ?

Comment: What are you expecting in parsedRes ? Since it is not getting anything, that is why you are getting undefined in alert1 and alert4. It is just showing fine.

Comment: I except imageUrl from firebase

Comment: Well, thats issue with your API then, You should test it before using in Angular. You can try Postman to test your API.

Comment: its Firebase, not my own api

Comment: yes, but whatever is your expectation like image or test, you can test it before using it in Angular

Answer (score 1):

You're not using promise chaining correctly.  You need to explicitly return the result of a `then()` callback to the next handler in the chain.  Without returning anything, the next `then()` callback will get undefined.  For example:

```
        .then(res => {res.json(); console.log("alert2 " + {res})})
```

In this line of code, you're not returning anything to pass along to the next handler in the chain.

In fact, the above `then()` callback is unnecessary because it's not kicking off any other async work.  You could just call `res.json()` in the subsequent `then()` block, just before the second fetch.  You typically only add another `then()` block when you have more async work to do as a result of the prior async work.